# How to use Taylor Hornby's password hashing functions

Tags: php, security, passwords, password-hash

I have been reading about password hashing. I really am not great at php. Could anyone tell me how to use Taylor Hornby's password hashing functions as seen [here?](https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing/blob/master/compatible/PasswordHash.php)

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first include the PHP file, you can see how to do that [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). You'd also need to customize the file to match what hash function you'd like to use. sha256 would be a good choice.

You would then run the `create_hash` function with your password, and store the returned value to your database.

To verify a password you'd run the `validate_password` function, with the hash from the database, and the password the user input. The other two functions you don't need to use, `validate_password` and `create_hash` run those for you with all the parameters you need.

Cryptography is complex and can be confusing, so it would be a good idea to read up on security a bit before storing confidential information like passwords, since setting this up wrong could mean your passwords are stored insecurely. [This page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) provides some technical details on how to securely store passwords.

Answer (score 2):

The class you linked to, implements a good algorithm (PBKDF2) to hash passwords, but there is a big problem with such implementations in PHP.

Appropriate hash algorithms for passwords include a cost factor, with which you can control the necessary time to calculate a hash-value. The higher the cost value is, the more rounds of hashing will be done. Since PHP is slower than a native C implementation, and you do not want to wait seconds for a login, you will do fewer rounds of hashing. This weakens the password-hashes, a cracker tool which can use the GPU will have a big advantage then.

That's why PHP offers a native implementation [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) of the BCrypt algorithm:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Use this function instead, even if the linked implementation seems to be well done.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing this question and discussing it with defuse, I've submitted the first example of his password hashing class in action. More to follow depending on demand and free time:

https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing/tree/master/examples